# Some problems calling a function into sprintf() inside functions.php template file

Tags: php, functions, themes, templates, add-theme-support

I am new in PHP and WordPress and I am personalizing an existent template and I have the following problem.

In the **function.php** file of the template I have the following function:

```
function admired_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span>
                 <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time>
                 </a>
                 <span>%5$s</span>
                 <span class="by-author"> 
                    <span class="sep"> by bla</span> 
                    <span class="author vcard">
                        <a class="url fn n" href="%6$s" title="%7$s" rel="author">%8$s</a>
                    </span>
                 </span>
                 ', 'admired' ),

    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    sprintf('Views: ', get_PostViews(get_the_ID())),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'admired' ), get_the_author() ),
    esc_html( get_the_author() )
    );
}
```

As you can see this function create some HTML code that will print in a specific part of my template (inside a loop).

Ok, as you can see this line:

```
sprintf('Views: ', get_PostViews(get_the_ID())),
```

should print the string "Views:" followed by the value returned by the function get_the_ID() (that rappresent the number of person that read a post)

As you can see this function is the fifth called in the list of called function, so this value should be put instead of the **%5$s** placeholder, into the following span tag:

```
<span>%5$s</span>
```

The proble is that whem I go to execute my page in this span appear only the value: **Views:** but don't appear the output of the get_PostViews() function.

If instead of the original line:

```
sprintf('Views: ', get_PostViews(get_the_ID())),
```

I use this line:

```
sprintf(get_PostViews(get_the_ID())),
```

it work well but so I can't preappend the explaination text: "Views:"

Why? what can I do to print the "Views" text followed by the returned value of my get_PostViews function?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: This is a **PHP** / **`sprintf()`** issue, *not* a **WordPress** issue.

Comment: I'm not sure the questioner knows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specifier in your sprintf, so it won't output anything. Try:

```
sprintf('Views: %d', get_PostViews(get_the_ID())),
```

You may have to use %s instead, it depends what your get_PostViews function is returning.